# Validate if a field value is greater than another model´s field

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have problems with the parameters, when The validator is written used this way:

```
    cantidadusada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=3,validators=[insumo_existencias])
```

It automatically gets the value of the respective field in the validator.py

```
def insumo_existencias(value):
#Por alguna razon, me esta devolviendo un string
insumo = models.Insumo.objects.get(id=1)

if (insumo.cantidadexistencias < value):
    raise ValidationError(
        _('Error no hay existencias suficientes'),
    )
```

So, I just have to call it value and that´s it, but when I want to pass another parameter,the function  does not longer get the value of the field. I tried this:

```
  cantidadusada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=3,validators=[insumo_existencias(cantidadusada,idinsumo)])
```

It is not working.
Obviosuly the validator function was changed to acept to parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in save function:

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    if (insumo.cantidadexistencias > value):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
       pass
       #do not save it!and raise error
```